# How to select first x records from second table

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to get all records from first table and only x records from second table.
How many records from second table I have info in first table :

My tables are

table1 :

```
WITH table1(a,b) AS
(
 SELECT 'aa',3 FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'bb',2 FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'cc',4 FROM dual
)
SELECT *
  FROM table1;
a  | b (number of records from table2 (x))
------
aa | 3
bb | 2
cc | 4
```

table2 :

```
WITH table2(a,b) AS
(
 SELECT 'aa','1xx' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'aa','2yy' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'aa','3ww' FROM dual UNION ALL  
 SELECT 'aa','4zz' FROM dual UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'aa','5qq' FROM dual UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'bb','1aa' FROM dual UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'bb','2bb' FROM dual UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'bb','3cc' FROM dual UNION ALL  
 SELECT 'cc','1oo' FROM dual UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'cc','2uu' FROM dual UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'cc','3tt' FROM dual UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'cc','4zz' FROM dual UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'cc','5rr' FROM dual
)
SELECT *
  FROM table2;
a  | b 
--------
aa | 1xx 
aa | 2yy 
aa | 3ww 
aa | 4zz 
aa | 5qq
bb | 1aa
bb | 2bb
bb | 3cc
bb | 4dd
bb | 5ee
cc | 1oo
cc | 2uu
cc | 3tt
cc | 4zz
cc | 5rr
```

Expected Result:

```
a  | b 
--------
aa | 1xx
aa | 2yy
aa | 3ww
bb | 1aa
bb | 2bb
cc | 1oo
cc | 2uu
cc | 3tt
cc | 4zz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function with `LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN` among the tables :

```
WITH t2 AS
(
SELECT t2.a,t2.b, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.a ORDER BY t2.b) AS rn
  FROM table2 t2
)
SELECT t2.a, t2.b
  FROM t2  
  LEFT JOIN table1 t1
    ON t1.a = t2.a  
 WHERE rn <= t1.b
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=552095b364d8e7c0a208e4c802aeb06e)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You need to write something like:

```
SELECT a,
       b
FROM   Table2 T, 
      ( SELECT LEVEL L FROM DUAL 
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX(b) FROM Table1) 
      ) A 
WHERE T.b>= A.L 
ORDER BY T.a;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but b in table 2 is not number. (WHERE T.b>= A.L)

Comment: I just need first x rows from second table. X is defined in table 1.

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT STATEMENTS. You will get your solution.

Comment: CREATE TABLE TABLE_1(T1_ADRESS  VARCHAR2(15 CHAR) NOT NULL, T1_NUMBER  NUMBER(2));
CREATE TABLE TABLE_2(T2_ADRESS VARCHAR2(15 CHAR) NOT NULL, T2_NAME VARCHAR2(15 CHAR));

Comment: Insert into TABLE_1 (T1_ADRESS, T1_NUMBER) Values (701', 3);
Insert into TABLE_1 (T1_ADRESS, T1_NUMBER) Values (702', 2);
Insert into TABLE_1 (T1_ADRESS, T1_NUMBER) Values (703', 4);

Comment: Insert into TABLE_2 (T2_ADRESS, T2_NAME) Values ('701','701A');
Insert into TABLE_2 (T2_ADRESS, T2_NAME) Values ('701','701B');
Insert into TABLE_2 (T2_ADRESS, T2_NAME) Values ('701','701C');
Insert into TABLE_2 (T2_ADRESS, T2_NAME) Values ('701','701D');
Insert into TABLE_2 (T2_ADRESS, T2_NAME) Values ('701','701E');

Comment: Insert into TABLE_2 (T2_ADRESS, T2_NAME) Values ('702','702A');
Insert into TABLE_2 (T2_ADRESS, T2_NAME) Values ('702','702B');
Insert into TABLE_2 (T2_ADRESS, T2_NAME) Values ('702','702C');
Insert into TABLE_2 (T2_ADRESS, T2_NAME) Values ('702','702D');
Insert into TABLE_2 (T2_ADRESS, T2_NAME) Values ('702','702E');

Comment: Insert into TABLE_2 (T2_ADRESS, T2_NAME) Values ('703','703A');
Insert into TABLE_2 (T2_ADRESS, T2_NAME) Values ('703','703B');
Insert into TABLE_2 (T2_ADRESS, T2_NAME) Values ('703','703C');
Insert into TABLE_2 (T2_ADRESS, T2_NAME) Values ('703','703D');
Insert into TABLE_2 (T2_ADRESS, T2_NAME) Values ('703','703E');

Comment: You should always include the DDLs and related DMLs in the original question. So that people will test their solutions. If you provide them in the comments, then they are unformatted and look clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have a ordering column in table2. When you say first X rows it does not make any sense unless you have something  like an id or date field to order the records.

Anyway, assuming the number part of the column b in table 2 for ordering and assuming the number would be followed by 2 characters only such as xx,yy etc you can use the logic below

```
Select Tb1.a, Tb1.b
from
(Select t.*, row_number() over (partition by a order by substr(b,1,length(b)-2)) as seq
 from Table2 t) Tb1
 join Table1 Tb2
on Tb1.a = Tb2.a
Where Tb1.seq <= Tb2.b;
```

Demo - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3030b2372bcbb007606bbb6481af9884

Answer (score 0):

Again it's just a job for lateral:

```
WITH prep AS 
( 
       SELECT * 
       FROM   tab1, 
              LATERAL 
              ( 
                     SELECT LEVEL AS lvl
                     FROM   dual 
                     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= b 
              ) 
) 
SELECT   p.a, t2.b
FROM     prep p 
JOIN     tab2 t2 
ON       p.lvl = regexp_substr(t2.b,'^\d+')
AND      p.a = t2.a 
ORDER BY p.a, p.lvl
```

[image]